# Watt meter for main panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm looking for a simple watt meter where I can connect both lines of my split phase and get a reading of how many watts and amps are flowing through.

I've seen something similar for solar systems but it's only one phase.

[Watt meter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5vMn.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to meter?  Your whole house, some subset of loads, an individual load?

Comment: I know of Sense, Curb, EKM, and Smappee. I'm just looking for something simpler for the whole house.

Comment: Is your utility kWh meter a "smart meter" (with a LCD/digital display) or an old-style electromechanical meter (with dials)?

Comment: It's Smart, but it only displays the current meter number, nothing else.

Comment: Do you actually need to see what is on **each** hot? Or just the total power consumption?

Comment: I just want to see Total power (Watt and Amps)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add an ammeter and/or voltmeter to my home breaker panel?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/178372/how-can-i-add-an-ammeter-and-or-voltmeter-to-my-home-breaker-panel)

Comment: Was looking for something simpler. Like the link above I added but with 2 amp meters for each phase.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a system called TED (The Energy Detective), it can be used to monitor the whole house or individual circuits, or both and gives you a simple interface either stand-alone or to your smart phone or tablet.