# Can I install an Ammeter in the cover of a junction box?

Tags: electrical, power-monitoring

I want to install an ammeter such as this: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B717PF6M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B717PF6M) to monitor my generator.

The idea would be to put a junction box in between the generator inlet and the interlock on my panel.  If I get a big enough junction box(probably more like a pvc project box) and I mount these to the cover?

If that's not possible is it ok to the CT Clamp wires to exit the junction box(or the panel itself) and mount these in there own box?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/178372/how-can-i-add-an-ammeter-and-or-voltmeter-to-my-home-breaker-panel may be of interest.

Comment: Please don't use link shorteners. Nobody likes clicking a link that will take them to who knows where. Please [edit] your question and put in the full link.

Comment: The linked device appears to be completely **unlisted** and is therefore not acceptable in any country with a half-way competent electrical code.  They are not even trying to fool you with a meaningless CE marking. No sign of UL or ETL, for my locality.

Comment: @FreeMan In general (bit.ly, etc. *ugh*) I agree. But a.co is actually a known Amazon-specific short domain.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I didn't necessarily mean that exact meter, just that style.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked quesion, I can heartily dis-recommend Murata as neat-o, feature-rich, and prone to dying, while having a useless warranty period.

Comment: Using a clamp ammeter involves no direct connection, and is more likely to meet code. That said, you'll need power for it, or be replacing batteries. There are many inexpensive plug-in *power outlet* meters, https://www.amazon.com/s?k=outlet+power+meter, and you might put a few in place to see which devices are using the most power. BTW, ammeters measure current, which, due to phase angle, can differ from power calculation of V x A.